# Issue in rendering drop down injsp

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I am trying to render a simple jsp page with one drop down in chrome. In normal web view it is working fine. But when I toggle the toolbar and click on the drop down I am not able to view the options instead a black block appears . I am attaching my jsp code snippet and the screen shot showing the issue.

Please help me out in solving this.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">

select {
width:100px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <select id="select">
      <option value="test">sssssssss</option>
      <option value="test2">ttttttttt</option>
   </select>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the drop down I cannot see the options instead a small black block appears in the page:

[image]

Comment: The black box is not showing in the snippet, therefore we cannot reproduce your problem. Take a look at what's different between the two.

Comment: I get this black box only if I load this page in chrome after toggling the device toolbar(in Responsive web view).You can recreate this issue by just developing a web project and use this jsp page in it and try to load this page on chrome in Responsive web view, otherwise it will work fine.